# Adding TabItems (with UserControl) to TabControl in C#: Binding Header is always empty

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, tabcontrol

I am trying to create a TabControl that can have multiple pages with the same input fields.

I have combined the input fields in a UserControl called TabContent. I have created a TabControl in the MainWindow, and I want to integrate TabItem headers from the MainWindow via the ItemTemplate resp. DataTemplate. In the MainWindow, I create a list of TabContents in which text is assigned to the headers. **This text is not displayed by the running programme as shown in the screenshot.** Any idea why and how to fix this?

[Screenshot with empty TabItem Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mgnwz.jpg)

Below is a minimal code example that reproduces the error.

```
// UserControl1.xaml.cs
namespace Nur_Test
{
    public partial class TabContent : UserControl
    {
        public TabContent()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Header { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
// UserControl1.xaml
<UserControl x:Class="Nur_Test.TabContent"
             // xmlns= [omitted...]
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Nur_Test"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="400">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox>Test</TextBox>   
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

```
// MainWindow.xaml
<Window x:Class="Nur_Test.MainWindow"
        // xmlns= [omitted...]
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Nur_Test"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl x:Name="tabControl1">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </TabControl>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
// MainWindow.xaml.cs
namespace Nur_Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<TabContent> items = new List<TabContent>()
        {
            new TabContent() { Header = "Item 1" },
            new TabContent() { Header = "Item 2" },
            new TabContent() { Header = "Item 3" },
        };

            tabControl1.ItemsSource = items;
        }


        public class TabItemData
        {
            public string Header { get; set; }            
        }
    }
}
```

It seems the binding that does not work. Putting a fixed string into the TextBlock instead of {Binding Header} in MainWindow.xaml works fine (but does not solve my problem):

```
<TextBlock Text="12345" />
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question, I'm still a beginner when it comes to C# :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `ItemsSource` to a `List<TabItemData>`:

```
List<TabItemData> items = new List<TabItemData>()
{
    new TabItemData() { Header = "Item 1" },
    new TabItemData() { Header = "Item 2" },
    new TabItemData() { Header = "Item 3" },
};

tabControl1.ItemsSource = items;
```

...and then use the `UserControl` in the `ContentTemplate`:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl1">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:TabContent />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

You are not supposed to set or bind the `ItemsSource` to a collection of UI elements such as `UserControls`.

Answer (score 0):

Your advice helped me a lot, *mm8*. In order for the code to finally work the way I wanted, I also had to create the class TabItemData. And I also needed to bind the content so that it would change when the tabs were clicked. Now it seems to work. Thank you very much!

Here are the final code modifications that worked for me:

```
// MainWindow.xaml.cs
public class TabItemData
 {
     public string Header { get; set; }
     public TabContent Content { get; set; }
 }
```

and

```
 // MainWindow.xaml.cs    
List<TabItemData> items = new List<TabItemData>()
{
    new TabItemData() { Header = "Item 1", Content = new TabContent() },
    new TabItemData() { Header = "Item 2", Content = new TabContent() },
    new TabItemData() { Header = "Item 3", Content = new TabContent() }
};
tabControl1.ItemsSource = items;
```

plus

```
// MainWindow.xaml   
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl1" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0">
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Header}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
  <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <ContentControl Content="{Binding Content}" />
    </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```